# grails spring security custom user registration page

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to create an app that uses Spring security core 2.0 and I'm trying to create a custom registration page. I think that my problem is in my register.gsp because everytime I try to register a new user it redirects to http://localhost:8080/home/register which is completely blank. Further evidence that this might be the case is that I included several println()s in my register action that should fire off depending on where the registration fails but none of them fire off at any time. Also, there are no users created in dbconsole. Please take a look at my gsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="front"/>
    <title>MSK | Register</title>
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <form action="${postUrl ?: '/home/register'}" method="POST" id="registerForm" class="cssform" autocomplete="off">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please register</h2>

            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="${usernameParameter ?: 'j_username'}"/>

            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="${emailParameter ?: 'email'}"/>

            <label for="fName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="text" id="FName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="${fNameParameter ?: 'fName'}"/>

            <label for="lName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="text" id="lName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="${lNameParameter ?: 'lName'}"/>

            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="${passwordParameter ?: 'j_password'}"/>

            <label for="confirmPassword" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="password" id="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="${passwordCParameter ?: 'confirmPassword'}"/>

            <g:actionSubmit style="margin-top: 20px" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" action="register" value="create"/>
            <button style="margin-top: 20px" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the controller and action, if that helps:

```
package com.mypackage
class HomeController {
    def springSecurityService

    //many actions

    def register(){
        switch(request.getMethod()){
        case 'POST':
            withForm {
                if(params.username && params.email && params.fName && params.lName && params.password && params.confirmPassword){
                    if(params.password == params.confirmPassword){
                        def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER', name: 'User').save(flush: true)
                        def newUser = User.findByUsername(params.id)
                        if(!newUser){
                            newUser.username = params.username
                            newUser.email = params.email
                            newUser.fName = params.fName
                            newUser.lName = params.lName
                            newUser.password = params.password
                            newUser.enabled = true
                            newUser.accountExpired = false
                            newUser.accountLocked = false
                            newUser.passwordExpired = false
                            newUser.authorities ?: userRole
                            if(loginService.register(newUser)){
                                flash.message = "Your account has been created. Welcome " + newUser.fName
                                flash.message_type = 'success'
                                redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'auth')
                            }else{
                                flash.message = "Unable to create your account. Please try again later"
                                flash.message_type = 'danger'
                                redirect(action: 'register')
                                println("saving user")
                            }
                        }else{
                            flash.message = "That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username."
                            flash.message_type = 'danger'
                            println("checking username")
                        }
                    }else{
                        flash.message = "Your passwords don't match. Please try again"
                        flash.message_type = 'danger'
                        println("matching passwords")
                    }
                }else {
                    flash.message = "Please fill out all required fields"
                    flash.message_type = 'danger'
                    println("filling out fields")
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'GET':
            break;
            println("POSTing form")
        }
    }
```

And here's the loginService's code too:

```
com.mypackage
//imports
@Transactional
class LoginService {
    def register(newUser){
        try{
            def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER', name: 'User').save(flush: true)
            newUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            UserRole.create(newUser, userRole, true)

            return true

        }catch(all){
            all.printStackTrace()
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

My apologies if all the code isn't properly indented, I basically copied and pasted out of my actual project. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- you can use the spring-security-ui plugin
- use command-object, which validate the password
- use resources, that means do a post to /user, that will call the save action